# C言語でファイルの数を取得することはできますか

Tags: c, ubuntu

コマンドでは`ls -U1 | wc -l`のように記述するとファイル数が帰ってくるようですが、C言語でファイル数を取得するにはどのようにしたらいいですか？

Comment: [opendir](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/ja/man3/opendir.3.html) して、[readdir](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/ja/man3/readdir.3.html)でエントリを読んでファイル種別を確認してカウントします。 [popen](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/ja/man3/popen.3.html)してもいいかと思いますけど。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ファイルかどうかをチェックした上でファイル数をカウントするのであれば以下のコードになるかと思います。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n = 0;
    struct dirent *de;
    DIR *d = opendir(".");
    while ((de = readdir(d))) {
        struct stat st;
        if (stat(de->d_name, &st) == 0 && st.st_mode & S_IFREG)
            n++;
    }
    closedir(d);
    printf("ファイルが %d 個あります\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```